# iPad/iPhone 2D array serialization

Tags: ipad, serialization

I have a 2D-array that defines points in one or more paths:

Path#1 = (1,1) (3,3) (6,6)

Path#2 = (5,3) (15,5) (16,46)

Here is my code

```
NSArray path1 = make array of CGPoints
NSArray path2 = make array of CGPoints

NSMutableArray paths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[paths addObject:path1];
[paths addObject:path2];
```

Question: How do I serialize/deserialize this object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as all of the objects in your arrays implement the `NSCoding` protocol, which most default classes do, you should be able to serialize the entire array structure using an `NSKeyedArchiver`.

If archiving/unarchiving directly to/from a file, it should look something like this:

```
NSString *filename = @"[filename]";
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:paths toFile:filename];
paths = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:filename];
```

If you just want raw data, maybe to shove in NSUserDefaults or to transmit over the network, it should look something like this:

```
NSData *binaryData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:paths];
paths = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:binaryData];
```

If you have custom classes in those arrays, you may have to implement `NSCoder` yourself, which is tedious, but not difficult.

Also, you may want to be careful with mutable arrays and dictionaries.  I seem to remember something about mutable objects becoming immutable when they're archived, so you might want to check before you just start adding objects.

Further reading:

[NSCoder Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCoder_Class/Reference/NSCoder.html)

[Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i)